# Given a graph G: how to find a formula to determine the number of squares in which a vertex participates?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I should find a formula that, given a certain vertex v1 of a graph G, it returns the number of squares in which v1 participates.

I managed to find a solution for triangles, but in the case of squares, I am a having a hard time trying to figure out how to build a formula that distinguishes those walks that form a square starting at v1 and finishing at v1 from those walks that have length 4 and which do not form an actual square.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.-

Comment: By a "square" you just mean a cycle of length $4$, don't you? Is the graph undirected? You want a formula in terms of what, the adjacency matrix of the graph? What is your formula for triangles?

Comment: Dear bof: sorry about the confusion. Yes, the graph is undirected. The formula should be in terms of the powers of the adjacency matrix. For example, for triangles, I should take the values of each vertex on the diagonal of A^3 and divide them by 2. Those would be the paths of length 3 that begin and end and each vertex. Therefore, they are triangles (I am discarding the counting on both directions by dividing the number by 2).

Comment: Dear Morgan, that's actually the main problem I can't solve: how to discard the 4-length walks that begin and end at v1 and which are not squares.
For example, given the adjacency matrix A = [0110;1001;1001;0110] then A^4 = [8008; 0880; 0880;8008]. The conclusion should be that there is only one square in which v1 participates (in this particular case, v1 could be any vertex of G). Nevertheless, it is not clear to me how to formally discard the other 7 walks that are of length 4, but are not squares. Any help would be appreciated since I am clueless.

Comment: Anyone? I would greatly appreciate any help on this matter :(

Comment: May be related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64777/counting-the-number-of-squares-in-a-graph